# free(); and malloc(); keeps crashing (C)

Tags: c, string, malloc, free

I built this code to practice pointers and the program keeps crashing.it seems it crashes when I enter a big number to `counter`. 1-5 doesn't affect it apparently, but when you enter 30 it keeps crashing, sometimes on the allocation itself `malloc(...` and sometime in the `free(names[i]);` function.

What's the problem here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    char **names;
    char buffer[100];
    int i, bufferLen, counter;

    printf("how many names? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &counter);
    if (counter < 0) {
        printf("wrong choice\n");
        return 1;
    }

    names = (char**)malloc(77 * sizeof(char));
    if (names == NULL) {
        printf("failed...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) { 
        printf("write the name!! (up to 100 chars): \n");
        gets_s(buffer, sizeof(char) * 100);
        bufferLen = strlen(buffer) + 1;
        names[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufferLen);
        if (names[i] == NULL) {
            printf("failed...\n");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy_s(names[i], sizeof(char)*bufferLen, buffer);
    }

    for (i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--) { //print names
        printf("no. %d, ptr no. %d (size: %d bytes): \n", i+1, (int)(names[i]), sizeof(names[i]));
        puts(names[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) { 
        if (names[i] != NULL)
            free(names[i]);
    }
    if (names != NULL)
        free(names);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your code has nothing to do with C++ then please do not use that tag. This code is pure C.

Comment: Doesn't seem causing the crash, but `sizeof(names[i])` is NOT the right way to get the buffer length.

Comment: @MikeCAT strlen() is only for debugging.

Comment: Bad SO etiquette to change the nature of the post once answers arrive.  Post roll-back

Comment: "when you enter 30 it keeps crashing" Is unclear.  Your entered 30 and code crashed or you  entered 30, later entered some names and then it crashed?  If it is the later case, please provide some sample input history that crash code.

Comment: Note: `if (names != NULL)
        free(names);` makes little sense.  `if (names == NULL)` was true the prior `names[i]` 3 lines up would be bad.  Good to check for `names != NULL` before using `names[i]`, not after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
names = (char**)malloc(77 * sizeof(char));
```

is wrong, `sizeof (char)` is 1 which is not what you want.

It should be:

```
names = malloc(77 * sizeof *names);
```

This is the same as `77 * sizeof (char *)` since `names` is `char **` which makes the type of `*names` be `char *`.

The cast is not necessary and should be omitted in my opinion.

It's very strange (and an obvious code smell) to use a literal `77` instead of `count` for the array length, of course.

Comment: Oops, 77- leftovers from the debugging... changed it.

Comment: @ArielAriel Did you only read that part, about `77`? I did write some more, didn't I?

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `names = (char**)malloc(counter * sizeof(char*));`.

Also `free` handles null pointers, no need to check the pointer for null before calling it.